# Long sentence: passive form, subject, 前に and 後

Tags: particles, passive-voice

So, I have 2 questions about this passage (a dialogue in chapter 11 of Tobira):

> **信長は**日本統一のために室町幕府の将軍に会おうとして、京都の本能寺とういお寺に泊まっていたんだ。そこに**明智が**攻めてきて**殺され**そうになったから、自分で切腹して死んだんだよ。死ぬ*前に*、燃えるお寺の中で能を舞った*後に*ね。

1. The use of passive: Nobunaga is being killed by Akechi, but this passage makes it seem like Akechi is the one being killed. I think that what is making me confused is the use of が after Akechi followed by a non-passive verb in て-form immediately followed by a passive one. How does this work?
2. The last part of the passage starts with 'before dying' and ends with 'after dancing'. It seems odd to me. Like, I get what it is trying to say but I can't understand the sentence's construction and how it coveys the meaning. I also can't seem to grasp the use of に after あと in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The subject 信長 is omitted throughout the sentence: そこに明智が攻めてきて(信長は)殺されそうになったから、(信長は/彼は)自分で切腹して死んだんだよ.

Just similar to the following:

- 雨が降ってきたから（わたしは）傘を差した It started to rain and (I) opened the umbrella.
- 彼が突然訪ねてきて（わたしは）驚いた He suddenly called on me and (I) was surprised

2. It does sound odd to me, too, but it is reasonable to think the relative clause is from the beginning up to 舞った: 「死ぬ前に、燃えるお寺の中で能を舞った」後にね= After dancing No in the temple on fire before death(seppuku).